# Broken multi line macro

Tags: c, macros

This multi line macro from the Nilorea library fails to compile when I include it in my C++ project. It is marked as extern "C".

Tried GodBolt, and the GCC 8.1 compiler barfs on the if statement in the following code : https://godbolt.org/z/Lq_7aT

```
#define Free( __ptr )\
    if (  __ptr  )\
    {\
        free(  __ptr  );\
        __ptr  = NULL;\
    }
int* i = 0;
Free(i);
```

It should compile. Is this a matter of the standard in use?

I edited the question with a bad compilable example.

Comment: What do you mean by saying a macro is marked as `extern "C"`?  That's meaningless to the C preprocessor!

Comment: Note: underscores are reserved for the compiler. And I assume you call your `Free(0)` inside a function?

Comment: The header it is defined in is marked as extern c

Comment: As `free(NULL)` is OK, the `if (  __ptr  )` test serves little use.

Comment: @chux you're missing context

Comment: You know you can run the compiler in godbolt with `-E` switch? https://godbolt.org/z/1Nyfvq This will eliminate the *macro* noise.

Answer (score 4):

The Godbolt code fails to compile because

- You are calling the code outside a function
- You are attempting to assign to literal 0
- You fail to include the necessary headers.

In addition, as noted in the comments, double underscore in identifiers is reserved for the implementation. The compiler doesn’t diagnose this but it’s illegal anyway.

When fixing these three issues, it works:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define Free(ptr) \
    if (ptr) \
    { \
        free(ptr); \
        ptr = NULL; \
    }

int main(void) {
    int *px = NULL;
    Free(px);
}
```

(I’ve also fixed the atrocious, inconsistent spacing.)

Comment: @Toby There’s no need to use `void` in a *definition*.

Comment: @KonradRudolph In terms of the letter of the C standard, yes, writing `(void)` as the parameter list of a function _definition_ is redundant.  However, every C compiler I can conveniently test gives the parameter list`()` the meaning "an unspecified number of arguments" in function definitions as well as in declarations, so it is good style to write it regardless.  (In C++, `()` and `(void)` are the same.)

Comment: @BugSquasher, is not because of the underscore, the culprit is this `0 = NULL;` you can not assign a value to a constant literal.

Comment: @BugSquasher your sample is not wrong because of the underscore (which doesn't cause problems in _this_ particular case), but because of point 1 and 3 mentioned in this answer. Point 2 is obsolete, because you've changed your code in the meantime.

Comment: @zwol I was convinced that `-Wextra` in GCC handled that. No idea how I got that idea (however, clang 8 *does* flag it).

Comment: Actually , it seems the real issue is with Free and other macro names being used by MinGW. I hate macros.

Comment: Okay, so it was a bad example. I'll try to improve next time, sorry.

Comment: @BugSquasher again, there is nothing wrong with your macro name, and if you hate macros, why do you use them? :P

Comment: Because the library I want to use (Nilorea) uses macros, and so does Windows.h, both of which pollute the namespace beyond aggravation. Not my choice to use macros.